# Need to Call a Print functionality using Apex Office print,on interactive report column

Tags: oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1, oracle-apex-18.2

Need to have a Print functionality in a Interactive Report using AOP plugin.

Apex office print works perfectly fine when I use a Button.
Steps: Create Dynamic Action On Button click, Action: APEX Office Print [AOP] - DA[Plugin]
write the SQL query to print the records in the AOP template PDF.

This works fine for me.

But my requirement is to have the Print Button on the Dashboard page.
1) Print can be used as a column in the Report.
2) Print can be a button on the Dashboard, which can check which record has been selected and needs to be printed taking the ID as a parameter.